# Как в CoffeScript/JS найти повторяющиеся слова в таблице?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Доброго времени суток. Как в таблице `html` (`<table> </table>`) найти повторяющийся слова и вывести на `html` страницу?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Например так (на JavaScript):

```js
var words = []; //массив для слов: words[n][0] - слово words[n][1] - кол-во

    function printUnicWords(table, elementForPrinting) { //основная функция
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); //все tr'ы таблицы

     initWordsArray(table);

     //занесение в массив
     for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td"); //все td'ы строки

      for(var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
       addWord(cols[j].innerHTML, false);
      }
     }

     //печать
     var forPrint = "";

     for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if(words[i][1] > 1) { //если слово встречается > 1 раза
       var postString = ", "; //строка после каждого слова

       forPrint += words[i][0] + ": " + words[i][1] + postString;
       
       elementForPrinting.innerHTML = forPrint.substring(0, forPrint.length - postString.length);
      }
     }
    }

    function addWord(word, mode) {
     //mode = false - auto-режим mode = true - режим добавления для нового слова
     /*функция работает так: если режим auto (mode = false), то перебирать
      все слова пока не встретится искомое, если искомого нет - запустить
      в режиме добавления нового слова (mode = true)*/

     for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if(!mode && words[i][0] == word) {
       words[i][1]++;
       break;
      } else if(!mode && i == words.length - 1) {
       addWord(word, true);
      } else if(mode && words[i][0] == "") {
       words[i][0] = word;
       words[i][1]++;
       break;
      }
     }
    }

    function initWordsArray(table) { //инициализация массива
     var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
     var trs = rows.length;
     var tds = rows[0].getElementsByTagName("td").length;

     for(var i = 0; i < trs * tds; i++) {
      words[i] = [];

      words[i][0] = "";
      words[i][1] = 0;
     }
    }
    
    //использование функции
    printUnicWords(document.getElementById("table"),
        document.getElementById("print"));
```

```html
<table id = "table">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<p id = "print"></p>
```

Comment: Какой то хардкод. Возможно можно как то легче?

Comment: @continue98 это не хардкод. Тут 50% - инициализация массива, 10% - печать. Проще - вряд ли, возможно у JS есть какие-нибудь встроенные функции для решения той или иной части поставленной задачи.

Comment: @continue98 убрал всё лишнее. Сократил с 81 до 58 строк. Проще некуда.

Comment: хорошо бы накинуть пример использования. =)

Comment: @continue98 пожалуйста.

Comment: а вообще нужно получить количество повторяющихся слов и вывести их количество, а не сами слова.

Comment: @continue98 т.е. например если есть слова: 1, 2, 3, 3, 2 - то нужно вывести 2, т.к. повторяются 2 и 3? И надо было добавить это в вопрос.

Comment: Есть конкретное слово, которое заранее известно в тексте, нужно подсчитать количество его повторов в тексте.

Comment: @continue98 и всё? Это же совершенно другая задача! Вопрос абсолютно иной!